# VR-Game - Synchronize Transform using Unity 2021, Mirror Network and XR Interaction Toolkit

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, mirror-networking

I am trying to create a simple VR-Game with objects that can be grabbed by the players and placed in a space.

I am using the XR Interaction Toolkit to make the objects grabbable and the Mirror Network Plugin to connect the players via a local server.

How can I sync the position of a grabbed and moved object to all connected clients?

I tried using the Network Transform (Client to Server) but I can only move the object on the server - and then it gets synced just fine. But I can not do it from the client side.

Any help would be much appreciated!

(I know this has already been asked, but I dont find the solution in the answers..)

Comment: What did you try from the existing answers you found?

Comment: I had found this similar..well actually same question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/199174/unity-xr-toolkit-and-mirror-networking-grabbing . But if the working solution is there I could not understand it.

Comment: I have a Network Transform on the object and it's set to "client to server". When I move it on the server (just altering the transform through a script) the object moves on all clients. It does not work the other way around though. Is that not the idea of "client to server"? Sorry I am very new to this...

Comment: I should add. I am trying this out right now on a simplified setup. Just trying to change the objects transform on a client and syncing it's position on the other clients. I hope that once I get that done, the step to the grabbing with the XR Toolkit is not so complicated..